# Apostrophes in PHP Xpath

Tags: php, dom, xpath, compiler-errors, apostrophe

What's up with apostrophes in Xpath? Nothing I try seems to work.

I'm trying to pick out items from an XML file by their titles using Xpath in DOM, but because some have apostrophes, it doesn't work.

I've tried replacing the apostrophes using this

```
$query1 = "channel/item[title='$p']/title";
```

but even that doesn't work. Any advice on how to do this, or alternatives for how to extract elements by their titles in DOM?

### Edit

Here's my code:

```
$q = $_GET["q"];

$q = explode('|^', $q);

$counts = count($q);

unset($q[$counts-1]);

$p = stripslashes($q);
$q = stripslashes($p);

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;

$dom->Load("../$userid.xml");

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

foreach ($q as $r) {

$p = preg_replace("/'/","&#146;",$r);

$query1 = "channel/item[title='$p']/title";
$query2 = "channel/item[title='$p']/url";
$query3 = "channel/item[title='$p']";

$entries = $xpath->query($query1);
$entries2 = $xpath->query($query2);
$entries3 = $xpath->query($query3);

foreach ($entries as $entry) {
foreach ($entries2 as $entry2) {
foreach ($entries3 as $entry3) {

$oldchapter = $entry->parentNode->removeChild($entry);
$oldchapter2 = $entry2->parentNode->removeChild($entry2);
$oldchapter3 = $entry3->parentNode->removeChild($entry3);

$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

}
}
}
}

$dom->formatOutput = true;

$dom->save("../$userid.xml")
```

Basically, my code extracts titles from a URL, separated by "|^" (For example title1|^title2|^title3|^). Because the "|^" is appended to the end of each title, I have to remove the empty value from the array. Then, because the titles with apostrophes come in like "Title\\'s", I have to strip slashes twice to get rid of them. Then I load a new DOMdocument, and find the titles from the URL in my existing XML document. Then I want the code to remove the whole items (titles, urls and the item itself) which have the same titles as the ones in the URL, and then save the document.

Comment: @karmafunk yeah, saw that, but It wasn't really what I was looking for, it just confused me more.

Comment: Shouldn't you be escaping them? Otherwise, PHP won't parse the `$p`.

Comment: @AlexW Yeah, that's what I'm trying to do

Comment: Can we see your code and any relevant data so we can try it ourselves?

Comment: Sorry about that, should have posted it earlier.

Comment: Yeah kinda stumped on this myself. What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: `$p = stripslashes($q);` [stripslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) expects the paramter to be a `String` and [explode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) returns an `Array`.  Does your `foreach` loop get executed?

Comment: @karmafunk I'm running 5.2.17

Comment: Can you write out the the value of $r and then $p after the preg_replace?

Comment: @karmafunk I don't understand what you mean.